# Custom Link of the home page section in menu is not working on other pages

Tags: wordpress, hyperlink, menu, header, customization

**I added custom link of the home page section in menu of WordPress website.**

[image]

> Link are working fine on home page

but when I go to the contact page then these custom links are not working.

[image]

Please developers give me a fine solution of this as soon as possible.

Comment: what result did you expect ? your url is an anchor that's mean if you doesn't have a link with name **Download** in your page it does nothing.

Comment: download link is working fine.  I have a feature and download section in my home page so when I am on contact page then the feature and download is not working..

Comment: I have a feature and download section in my home page. Download and Features links are working fine. so when I am on contact page then the feature and download are not working.

Comment: Thats normal that's what i try to explain to you, if you want to redirect your user always in your homepage to the section download you have to make the full link to your home page with your anchor #Download

Comment: I also tried full link but that is not working also

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52073575/12129459 it works for me. You should also try this at once.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will work if you made some changes in the link that you added in the menu.
you have to write the **homepage** link first and then add the **ID** of the home page section after forward slash (/)

> **`www.homepage.com/#download`**

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue,I had an *id* in my **Service** page called *health* and i wanted to access it from the menu.

This was how i resolved it.
I simply did  `/services/#health` and it worked.

I am assuming your download *id* is in your **home** page, then do `/home/#download` in the url.